# Flutter - semi-transparent page not working properly when using PageRouteBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I'm having difficulty getting a page with a transparent background, so it appears as an 'overlay' over the previous page, to work properly.

The original page this page is being opened *on top of* (ie. the one which should be visible below the new page) is opened like this:

```
Navigator.push(
  PageRouteBuilder<T>(
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: duration),
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => OriginalPage(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return FadeThroughTransition(
        animation: animation,
        secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
        child: child,
      );
    },
  )
);
```

The code to push the new page on top is:

```
Navigator.of(context)
  .push(PageRouteBuilder(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
      opaque: false,
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      reverseTransitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        double begin = 0;
        double end = 1;
        var curve = Curves.easeIn;
        var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));
        final offsetAnimation = animation.drive(tween);
        return BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 24 * offsetAnimation.value, sigmaY: 24 * offsetAnimation.value),
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: offsetAnimation,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) => NewPage()
 ));
```

The strange thing is that if I use a standard MaterialPageRoute when pushing the original page, the page pushed on top of it behaves normally -- the background is transparent, the blur effect works as intended. The issue seems to be with the use of PageRouteBuilder, or perhaps FadeThroughTransition.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

What is `FadeThroughTransition`?

##### Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Try this code instead:

```dart
class OriginalPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Image.network('image_link'),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            PageRouteBuilder(
              barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              opaque: false,
              pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => NewPage(),
              transitionsBuilder: (_, animation, __, child) {
                return BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                    sigmaX: 10 * animation.value,
                    sigmaY: 10 * animation.value,
                  ),
                  child: FadeTransition(
                    opacity: animation,
                    child: child,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is your `NewPage` class.

```dart
class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // Set this to transparent
      body: Center(child: Text('Page 2')),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help. As stated in my question, the behaviour is a result of using PageRouteBuilder to push the _original_ page. I'm looking for a way to use PageRouteBuilder without having this issue. Your answer just gives me an alternative way of achieving the undesired behaviour I outlined.

Comment: @mosh.jinton Your code wan't reproducible so I gave you an idea how you can solve it.

Comment: [This](https://pub.dev/documentation/animations/latest/animations/FadeThroughTransition-class.html) is FadeThroughTransition, from the animations package, first result if you google FadeThroughTransition. I should have specified that though.

I do appreciate your attempt to help, but your answer was irrelevant to the question I had asked so I just explained why.

Comment: @mosh.jinton Actually I hardly use packages and therefore I'm not very good in answering these type of questions. So, had I known if it was a package, I probably won't have answered your question in the first place and you came back after two weeks on this thread.